# Serilog + serilog-sinks-elasticsearch +ElasticSearch Auth

Tags: .net, logging, elasticsearch, serilog

I am far from being a Dev with any .net experience, but the dev team at work would like to use Serilog along with serilog-sinks-elasticsearch to push logs into my ELK stack.

Looking at the config for serilog-sinks-elasticsearch, there doesn't seem to be any way to send the creds require to write to the ElasticSearch Cluster.

Is this just a dumb ops person question or have I just missed the config somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I struggled to find a good solution for this too. Adding the username/password to the url definitely does work but somehow doesnt feel right.

This worked for me:

```
.WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri("https://your-deployment.westeurope.azure.elastic-cloud.com:9243"))
{
  ...,
  ModifyConnectionSettings = x => x.BasicAuthentication("elastic", "your-password"),
})
```

Answer (score 10):

Good question....

You might try supplying them as part of the Elasticsearch server/stack URL.

Example:

```
.WriteTo.Sink(new ElasticsearchSink(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri(url))
{
    AutoRegisterTemplate = true
}
```

where

```
url = "https://user:password@stack-server:port"
```

Comment: It looks like specifying credentials in URL works for a single node only. If credentials are specified for several nodes divided by ; or , logging stops working. Tried in .Net Core 3.1. Settings in appsettings.json

Answer (score 9):

If you want to stick with your configuration file (appsettings.json), knowing that you can use the argument connectionGlobalHeaders to specify the login/password, because Elasticsearch use Basic Authentication to authenticate the user.

Something like this:

```
"Serilog": {
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Elasticsearch",
        "Args": {
          "nodeUris": "https://your-uri",
          "connectionGlobalHeaders": "Authorization=Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=",
          "indexFormat": "application-log-{0:yyyy.MM}",
          "autoRegisterTemplate": true,
          "autoRegisterTemplateVersion": "ESv7"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

where the part after "Authorization=Basic" is the Base64 string of your "login:password".

Comment: for the login:password Base64 string. Do I convert it exactly like that? "user134:pass432" or is it "user134pass432"?

Comment: It is with the colon in the middle, i.e. "user134:pass432".

Answer (score 0):

If Serilog doesn't sends data to your log server make sure that the version of elastic is compatible with the sink, It took me hours to figure that out :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).